# React native - how to keep TabNavigator in every screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigator, tabnavigator

I am using a combination of tab navigator, stack navigator, and switch nagivator in my react native app with `react-navigation`.

This works well, except I'd like to keep the bottom tabs in every screen. Currently if I navigate to `UserProfile` screen, then the bottom tabs go away.

App.js:

```
const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Feed: { screen: FeedScreenStack },
  MyProfile: { screen: ProfileScreenStack },
});

const UserStack = createStackNavigator(
  { 
    UserProfile: { screen: userProfile },
    Comments: { screen: comments }
  }
);

const MainStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Home: TabStack,
    User: UserStack,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
);
```

To solve this, I tried making a component out of the tab navigator and just importing it in `userProfile.js`, like `<BottomTab />`.

bottomTab.js:

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Feed: { screen: FeedScreenStack },
    MyProfile: { screen: ProfileScreenStack },
})

export default BottomTab
```

but this doesn't work because in react-navigation 3 I have to set up the app container directly and I am not sure how to get around it. The only other solution I can think of is to create a custom component that is just a bar with buttons pointing to different pages, but I wonder if I can just use TabNavigator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way is that a TabNavigation is the Top Item in your navigation stack. In each of the tabs you might have a different StackNavigation. If you use the SwitchNavigation for Auth which probably means a Login-Screen, you might put the SwitchNavigation at top with the two children Auth and Tab and include Home, User, Feed, etc. in different StackNavigations that are children of the TabNavigation. You could change for example as following:

```
const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Feed: { screen: FeedScreenStack },
  User: { screen: UserStack },
});

const UserStack = createStackNavigator({ 
  UserProfile: { screen: userProfile },
  Comments: { screen: comments },
  MyProfile: { screen: ProfileScreenStack },
});

const MainStack = createSwitchNavigator({
  Home: TabStack,
  Auth: AuthStack
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Home'
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me because `User` is a screen that can be reached from clicking on one of the users in `Feed`, it isn't a stand alone screen. That's why originally I had `UserStack ` by itself. And yes, Auth is for login

Comment: then you need to add `User` also to your `FeedScreenStack`. If you want to switch the tab in this case you would need to switch the Tab-navigation as well, which is irritating for users, I would not recommend this.

Comment: "If you want to switch the tab in this case you would need to switch the Tab-navigation as well, which is irritating for users, I would not recommend this", I don't understand, can you elaborate on what is the issue exactly? If you mean, when I switch from `MyProfile` back to `Feed`, I would land on `UserProfile` and need to click the back button to fully go back to `Feed` then I guess we may just be have different opinions on UX. Or is this generally not recommended?

Comment: I read the iOS Human Interface Guidelines this way and I do not remember to have seen a switch of the Tab due to an action on the Tab, but of course you can do that if you think that fits your use case better. I personally would expect a Stack-Navigation with push and pop inside each tab, but it probably depends on the case.

Comment: And your recommendation is to always have `TabNavigator` as the top item inside a `SwitchNavigator`?

Comment: if you use the SwitchNavigator to switch between Login and regular App Usage, this is an option, but TabNavigator has to be on top to always stay visible in the sub-components. You can also use a single StackNavigator and Modal Components, but you were asking to have TabNavigator always visible